# How can I select, with css, a nested div that is on the same level with other divs?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am trying to target, with css, the `<canvas>`, but it doesn't work because the div containing the `<canvas>` is on the same level with other divs and I don't know how to target it. I made here a simplified version of my problem. I cannot use classes in my case, I need to target the `<canvas>` like this:

```
.sectionHomepage > div > div > div canvas {
  width: 100%;
}
```

but it doesn't work

Here is the simplified structure of my problem:

```
<li className={css.sectionHomepage}>

   <div>
      <div>

          <div>
          </div>

          <div>
              <canvas>
              </canvas>
          </div>

          <div>
          </div>

      </div>
   </div>

</li>
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong ? Or how can I target the `<canvas>` in the way I want ?

Comment: Why not `.sectionHomepage canvas` ???

Comment: @ManasKhandelwal solution should work

Comment: The CSS looks more specific than it needs to be, but should correctly select the element with the given markup. Are you sure there are no typos somewhere?

Comment: Doesn't work :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I misunderstood the issue and give a wrong answer before. The right answer would be that your CSS selector is right, but probably you mistyped the HTML.

Try to change your HTML from this:

`<li className={css.sectionHomepage}>`

To this:

`<li className={css.sectionHomepage} class={css.sectionHomepage}>`

I don't know why you need the `className`, the thing is that for sure you need the `class` attribute.

Take a look in the working version on codepen: https://codepen.io/marcelkohls/pen/NWdweme

Comment: Can you explain why the provided CSS did not work?

Comment: I don't know why, I also think it should work

Comment: @BogosRobert I've fixed my answer, now it must work

Answer (score 0):

Like @ManasKhandelwal suggested : `.sectionHomepage canvas` will target the canvas as wanted.
https://codepen.io/JuPic/pen/qBRVQpw : In the devtool you can see that the style `width: 100%` was applied correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about ReactJs so I don't understand that kind of class name with the curly brackets, but I can still demonstrate how to target the nested element with standard JS, so here goes...

I'll just replace your class name with "abc" for this demo:

```
var e=document.querySelectorAll('LI[class*="abc"]')[0].getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
```

So "e" now is your canvas element. I basically queried the LI with that class, and then queried further into it for a canvas element.

NB: I'm assuming there's only ONE LI with that class name and hence the [0]